# LockService: How do I lock a Google sheet from within a script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, locking, mailchimp, contact-form-7

I'm using a Google spreadsheet to store contact info I collect from a website (GDPR compliant, don't worry) and I synchronize this sheet with Mailchimp using a custom App script, which runs in the background.

More in detail, I'm using a temporary sheet as a buffer which is filled with the data users send via the site's forms (I'm using Contact Form 7 Google Sheets Connector). My script runs each time the event INSERT_ROW is triggered in the "buffer" sheet. It analyzes the data, stores them in the final sheet and, eventually, it emptys the "buffer".
Now, aware of potential concurrency issues I've written the code in the following form:

```
function onChange(e) {
  // Script initializaztion

  if (!formNames.includes(formName) || e.changeType != "INSERT_ROW") return;

  let lock = LockService.getScriptLock();

  try {
    lock.waitLock(60000);

    // Get new stuff from Form sheet
    .
    .
    .

    // Get existing data and compare with new
    compareData();

    // New entries
    insertNewDataIntoFinalSheet();

    // Updates
    updatesExistingDataInFinalSheet();

    // Clean up the buffer sheet
    deleteRowsFromSiteForms();

    console.log(formName);

  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

  lock.releaseLock();
}
```

But I'm not sure the Lock is doing what I'm expecting it to do. And Google Docs are not so clear about its use.
If I'm not understanding Google docs wrong, any Lock is

> preventing sections of code from running concurrently.
>   This service allows scripts to prevents concurrent access to sections of code. This can be useful when you have multiple users or processes modifying a shared resource and want to prevent collisions (Google docs).

Now Imagine the following scenario: User A in his browser fills in the form. At the very same time (well, almost) User B is doing the same in another browser somewhere else in the world. The CF7 connector of User A's browser sends data to my "buffer" sheet and it gets the lock so that my script begins its work. A nanosecond later, users B's form inserts other data into the "buffer" triggering thus a script execution. This new script instance tries to acquire the lock but is blocked by user A's lock.

In the mean time, User A's script instance is finishing its job and cleans up everything, *deleting also the data input by User B*! When user A's script instance releases the lock, user B's script kicks in, but it finds its data swept away by user A's script instance.

Ideally, what I need is a way to "freeze" any modification to the "buffer" sheet (including insertion of new rows) until each script instance has finished its job.

But as far as I understand, and also judging by some strange errors I have in my logs, this is not what getScriptlock() is doing (and getUserlock() or getDocumentlock() neither).

Can anyone help me understanding how I should use Google LockService for that?

Thank you in advance

### EDIT

Those who have commented my post (@TheMaster in particular) have caught the very core of the problem, so let me add some further information/thought.  This is the the error I'm getting (sometimes) in my Stackdriver Log

[image: Error log from Stackdrive]

Apparently, my script is trying to access data when it is not supposed to. I suspect it is the scenario I've depicted: the second instance of the script finds the "buffer" emptied by the first instance.

As @TheMaster says, the problem is that there's no way to really "lock" a document if the document is accessed via some external resource, like Zapier, for example, or, as in my case, a Wordpress connector, or any API request (Google developers, shouldn't you address this issue?).

Comment: Can I ask you about `some strange errors I have in my logs`?

Comment: @Tanaike OP probably means userB logs are found in between userA logs or something like that. Just like OP, I was never able to get a lock when 1. Data comes from  outside through sheets api or addon/Zapier(non -human trigger) 2. The function trigger is a installed onChange.  To reproduce, those two conditions must be satisfied. It's like several separate instances of the script are running at the same time.  In any case, `@`Raff Clarify those errors as requested by Tanaike preferably with proof/screenshots.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for your support. When users are accessed to Spreadsheet using each browser, the lock service can be used. But when the Spreadsheet is directly edited by Sheets API, the lock service cannot be used. In this case, when the script using Sheets API is run, it is required to protect the Spreadsheet using the script. And the script is required to include the process for not accessing to the protected Spreadsheet. I'm not sure whether this is the direction OP wants.

Comment: @Tanaike That's a interesting workaround. But there's no official information about this: **But when the Spreadsheet is directly edited by Sheets API, the lock service cannot be used.** right?

Comment: @TheMaster I think that it's yes. Because when the Spreadsheet is directly edited from outside by Sheets API, OnChange event trigger is not run and `LockService.getScriptLock()` cannot be run. As another workaround, I think that if the Spreadsheet is edited by Web Apps, the Spreadsheet can be locked because Web Apps includes the script of `LockService.getScriptLock()`.

Comment: @Tanaike "*when the Spreadsheet is directly edited from outside by Sheets API, OnChange event trigger is not run*" - Not true. OnChange event is captured,  even if the edit is made by sheets api and `LockService.getScriptLock()` **is** run, but it doesn't actually lock. This is the problem for op.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for replying and adding the information. From my experience, I had thought that in that case, OnChange event trigger doesn't work. From your replying, I could understand that although OnChange event trigger is run, the script of `LockService.getScriptLock()` doesn't work. In this case, how about protecting Spreadsheet during the script is running?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes. That is what I thought you were suggesting at first. But not sure how effective it would be.

Comment: @TheMaster About this, it might be required to test it at the actual situation whether this can be used.

Comment: Using getDocumentLock won't work for your case, because as stated in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock-service#getdocumentlock) it "gets a lock that prevents any user of the current document from concurrently running a section of code". So it locks the code you're using inside the trigger function to edit the final sheet and it'll prevent the collisions for the final sheet (as the code for edit it is within the lock), but not for the "buffer" Spreadsheet which is being edited with an external request.

Comment: As @Tanaike mentioned, you could [protect](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#protect) the buffer sheet within the trigger function to avoid the collisions.

Comment: @Tanaike I confirm what _TheMaster_ says, my script _is_ executed exactly by the INSERT_ROW event triggered by the users filling up the forms in the browsers (i.e. rows are inserted via API). The event doesn't fire if rows are inserted by means of Google scripts themselves.

Comment: @AndresDuarte The idea of "protecting" temporarily the buffer sheet is something I've thought of, but eventually I've discarded the idea. If some external API tries to insert data into the buffer while the script is running (i.e. the buffer sheet is protected) the insertion will fail. A well conceived lock mechanism is meant to temporarily freeze and properly enqueue write request, not to let them fail.

Comment: A dirty workaround could be the use of a time driven event instead of the onChange(INSERT_ROW) one, but I fear that it would not address the root of the issue. I can setup a trigger for running the script only once per day, at midnight for example, assuming that everybody goes to bed earlier, but if someone suffers from insomnia, the issue might pop up again. Not very likely, but _might_...

Answer (score 1):

> Google developers, shouldn't you address this issue

I would've reported it, but, you see, the restrictions of a installable trigger are clear:

> [Script executions and **API requests** do not cause triggers to run.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions)

So, I didn't want them to "fix" it by removing this functionality altogether. Then you'd have to poll at regular intervals, which would be a pain.

If two INSERT_ROWs are done by the api at say,

- rows 21 to  25  and
- at rows 26 to 30.

Even though the external api inserts the rows in order, sometimes, the latter is triggered first(say at 23:00) and the former is triggered last(at 23:01). The former's `sheet.getLastRow()` may still be 30(even though it was triggered for row insertion 21 to 25, because it was triggered late). One solution would be to let everything run async: Inside the change event trigger function,  The `active range` refers to the range currently added by the api. The dimensions of the "INSERT_ROW" can be obtained by:

```
  const rng = ss.getActiveRange(); //Currently Active Range
  const row = rng.getRow(); //Active Row number
  const col = rng.getColumn(); //Active Column number
  const lrow = rng.getLastRow(); //Last Row in Active range
```

Notice that the last row is inferred by `rng.getLastRow()` and not `sheet.getLastRow()`. So, even if the latter is triggered first, We only get the currently added rows in that instance of script execution(i.e., rows 26 to 30). You maybe able to leverage that to get a true async workflow.

Comment: Thank you TheMaster, I'll give it a try. Nevertheless, the fact that API calls **don't** fire the INSERT ROW event sounds strange. I don't know the internals of the GoogleSheets CF7 Connector Plugin (Wordpress) I'm using, but my guess is that it's using some form of API calls. And my onChange function **is** called when someone submits the CF7 form.

Comment: @Raffa I agree and I can confirm the same with sheets api call. I'm saying it works, but officially it shouldn't.