# GAS "On edit" trigger not running when edited from API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I was wondering if someone encountered this issue and thought of a workaround that isn't awful.

I have a trigger on Google Spreadsheets that is configured "on edit", and it works fine if the edit occurs manually (or via formula) **from within the spreadsheet itself**. However if I modify a cell externally from the [Sheets API v4](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update), the cell is changed but the function isn't triggered. Am I missing something, or Google simply doesn't support triggering when change comes from "outside"?

**EDIT:**
As per @TheMaster's suggestion, I wrote:

```
function test_on_change(e){
  console.log("Changed");
  console.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getA1Notation());
}
```

The `e` object is `json` of the `enum` that is described [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change).

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, that is the specification at Google side. So, as one of several workarounds, when you request the Sheets API in your script, how about running the function of Google Apps Script using Web Apps and/or Apps Script API?

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks, I didn't know I could run an Apps Script function remotely. I'll try that doing that whenever I modify something from the API. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for replying. You have already used Sheets API. From this situation, I think that running the function of Google Apps Script with Web Apps is easy to implement to your current script. When your issue was resolved, could you please post it as an answer? I think that your question and answer will be also useful for other users. When you want to see more information of Web Apps, how about [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) and [this](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)?

Comment: I could understand that my proposal was not suitable from [TheMaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60929262/7108653). This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: Is there a new question? It's preferable to ask follow up questions in a new post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`onChange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change) installable trigger works with edits made from sheets api. It is possible to get the edited range using `.getActiveRange()` calls.

Comment: I had never tested about the OnChange event trigger for this situation which puts the value to the cells using Sheets API. I could obtain new information from your answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks. I tested and it works. I believe I read that this is a possibility first from a comment made by ``@Serge insas``.  Also, this was what I was talking about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60399693/lockservice-how-do-i-lock-a-google-sheet-from-within-a-script/60431717#comment106866332_60399693)

Comment: @TheMaster Thanks, I do see that OnChange is being triggered, but I don't see how I have access to the changed data. You said ".getActiveRange()", but in the function I only get an "authMode" enum just like it says here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change

Comment: I tried ".getActiveRange()" on the active sheet, but it returned an empty object.

Comment: @Cauthon `range` will be a empty object. Try `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getA1Notation()`

Comment: @TheMaster This is always empty as well. It says in the docs that I should only get those 4 outputs `authMode`, `changeType`, etc. But I don't think that data shows the actual edit...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210600/discussion-between-cauthon-and-themaster).

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in the [Trigger Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions):

> Script executions and API requests do not cause triggers to run. For
>   example, calling Range.setValue() to edit a cell does not cause the
>   spreadsheet's onEdit trigger to run.

In case you want to deploy the script as a Web App as Tanaike mentioned, you might want to check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).

Comment: I could understand that my proposal was not suitable from [TheMaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60929262/7108653). This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.