# How can I automatically add current date when a cell is filled?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

SoI'm using Google Sheets and I have an Activecampaign integration that adds a new row when a new user subscribe. I would like to add, with the user info, the current day - so I can know when people got in my list.

I have 4 tabs. The one that I want the day is called "leadData".

I tried this code, but it's not working:

```
function onChange(e) {
   var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName("leadData")
   columnToWatch = 1,
   columnToStamp = 7, //change all of these to your needs...1 is column A, 2 is column B, etc
   excluded = ["General Info", "Campaigns", "Automations"]; //add names of sheets/tabs to this list. The script will not work on these sheets.
   if (e.range.columnStart !== columnToWatch ||  !e.value || excluded.indexOf(sheet.getName()) > -1) return;
   sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, columnToStamp)
       .setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd HH:mm");  
}
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of `In my case, I'm using an API to fill my cells, and the code is not working.`?

Comment: @Tanaike I'm using ActiveCampaign integration with Google Sheets to send data. So the cells are being filled automatically

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, you want to run the Google Apps Script when the value is put to the cells using Sheets API from outside. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike yes! That's it

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, please use the OnChange event trigger instead of the OnEdit event trigger. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60929262/7108653) I think that by this, your goal can be achieved.

Comment: @Tanaike thank you so much! Do you have any sample code to fit in my case? In my head I just ned to change de "onEdit(e)" and "e.source.getActiveSheet()". Am I right?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I cannot understand about your replying, this official document is useful? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Comment: @Tanaike sorry for not being clear! What I mean is: do you have any sample code that I can use to add the date? Because reading this docs I think that changing "function onEdit(e) {" to "function onChange(e) {" would solve it

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. When your script is modified, at first, please modify the function name from `onEdit` to others, and install the OnChange event trigger to the changed function name. In this case, you can use various function names. Because the OnChange event trigger is not the simple trigger. And if you want to run the script for the specific sheet, please modify to `var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName("sheetName")`.

Comment: @Tanaike first: thank you so much for your help. REALLY. Second: just updated my code in my question. Does it look ok?

Comment: Thank you for replying. At first, can I ask you whether your this question was resolved? And please modify your question as resolved answer. When your question was resolved, please post it as an answer. By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: @Tanaike so I just tested it and didn't work. As I said, I change the code to the code that I think it's right. Can you check it?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your current situation from your replying. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: @Tanaike no problem! I change the code from my question. Can you look and see if it is right?

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I could correctly understand about your current issue, I would like to think of the issue. So when you add more detail information for your current situation and issue, it will help users including me think of the solution. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike perfect! Change my whole question. Take a look now

Comment: `e.source` doesn't exist for `onChange(e)` triggers. You'll need to use `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("leadData");` instead. You say `I just tested it and didn't work`, could you elaborate on this please? What is it doing that is not as you expect? Have you installed the trigger from the `Edit > Current project's triggers` menu item and clicked `+ Add Trigger`?

Comment: @guilherme are you still encountering this issue?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo sorry for not answering you. The error is that the date is not being added. I changed the code in my answer to the code that I'm using right now. And yes, I did the trigger!

Comment: There is no `e.range` for `onChange()` triggers. It's not possible to enter data in the sheet based on where the range of the change was for this reason. Check out the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change). You'll need to go about this a different way depending on how the data is inputted from Activecampaign; if it's always a new appended row then instead of `e.range.rowStart` you could potentially use `sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows()` instead.

Comment: @guilherme Has this solved your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*The `source` and `range` fields are not part of the event object for `onChange` triggers. You must specify the Sheet and rows you want directly.*

#### More Information:

As per the documentation on [event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change), the Google Sheets `onChange()` trigger is an installable trigger and does not have the `source` nor the `range` fields in the event object that it gets passed.

#### Code Modifications:

You need to specify the sheet directly. Change the following line

```js
var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName("leadData");
```

to:

```js
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("leadData");
```

and change

```js
sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, columnToStamp)
     .setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd HH:mm");
```

to

```js
sheet.getRange(sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows(), columnToStamp)
     .setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd HH:mm");
```

#### References:

- [Event Objects | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [Installable Triggers | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)