# Replicating "onEdit" behaviour for automatically populated fields from third-party integration

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm generating a timestamp column to record when edits have been made in another column of the same row.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var column = e.range.getColumn();
  if (column == 3) { // Only if edited column is the third one
    var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), e.source.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    //set timestamp in the first column in the same row
    e.range.getSheet().getRange(row, 1).setValue(formattedDate);
  }
}
```

When I make an edit myself, it works well. However I need to work even when the 'edit' is made by a third-party integration (manychat), which is automatically populating the content in the watched column.

Ultimately, I want a timestamp of WHEN the third-party integration places data in that column.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60926676

Answer (score 0):

The installable `On change` trigger is triggered when an API make changes to the spreadsheet. As the `change` event object hasn't the same properties as the `edit` event object, you might add the missing properties, then call the `onEdit` function:

```
function respondToOnChange(e){
  if(e.changeType === 'EDIT'){
    e.range = e.source.getActiveRange();
    e.range.rowStart = e.range.getRow();
    e.range.columnStart = e.range.getColumn();
    // add the other properties that are needed
    onEdit(e);
  }
}
```